# What is the meaning of MOV (%r11,%r12,1), %edx?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, mov, addressing-mode

What does this instruction do?

```
mov (%r11,%r12,1), %edx
```

Comment: See also the [AT&T syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) for more details on the syntax, and links to more docs.

Comment: Related: [A couple of questions about \[base + index\*scale + disp\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936196)

Answer (score 7):

Look [here](http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax). It says

> In the AT&T Syntax, memory is
>   referenced in the following way,
>
> ```
> segment-override:signed-offset(base,index,scale)
> ```

Down on the page there are some examples. I find this the best:

```
GAS memory operand   NASM memory operand
------------------   -------------------
(%ecx,%ebx,2)    [ecx+ebx*2]
```

`mov source, destination` in AT&T syntax copies the value from source to destination. Also consider the size of edx. How many bytes (4) do you think `mov` will copy ?

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

`mov (%r11,%r12,1), %edx` this instruction is use to calculate the address (indexed addressing mode).

- `%r11` is a base adress
- `%r12` is a index
- and `1` is a multipler

It's work like this:

**adres = base adres + index * multipler**

base adres and multipler must be constants (base adress can be register), index must be register.