# What does movsbq and this add line do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode, sign-extension

I am trying to figure out what these lines of code do

movsbq (%rbx),%rcx

and

add   (%rdx,%rcx,4),%eax

Comment: This isn't really a good question for this site. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of MOV (%r11,%r12,1), %edx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883850/what-is-the-meaning-of-mov-r11-r12-1-edx)

Comment: And of [Please verify meaning of AT&T Assembly line](//stackoverflow.com/a/14954482) for the `movsbq`  (I broke my duphammer by removing `[x86]` and adding `[x86-64]`, oops.  Even though I have a gold badge in both tags)

Answer (score 2):

MOVSBQ reads one byte from the source, signs extends it to a quad word (64 bits, replicating bit 7 into bits 63:8) and writes the value to the destination register.

The addressing mode (%r1,%r2,4) computes the address of the operand as R1 + R2 * 4. The ADD instruction reads the DWORD at that address and adds it to EAX.